# mySQL transaction race condition issue

Tags: mysql, transactions, race-condition

I have two concurrent transactions, using mySQL inno db

T1:

```
select row from table A
if row exists
    insert row in table B with fk to table A
else
    insert row in table A
    insert row in table B with fk to table A
```

T2:

```
delete row from table A (same row as T1 is selecting/updating)
```

The problem is, T1 executes and row exists, so it tries to insert in table B with fk to table A, but right before the insert, T2 executes, deletes table A row, and commits, now T1 will fail to insert in table B because there is no row in table A anymore.
Shouldnt T1 and T2 be serialized? Either T1 executes first, or T2, but not both mixed up. I know this can be fixed using a select for update statement to lock but the actual logic is way more complicated than this and completely locking a table would really hurt performance.

Comment: Using `FOR UPDATE` will make them serialized. Why is it completely locking the table? Can you post the relevant fields and indexes for table A?

Comment: Prolly because the ORM, im not using the db directly, currently using django.